# Study of the convergence of a sequence with repeated radicals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, nested-radicals

Consider the sequence
$$
a_n = \sqrt {1!\sqrt {2!\cdots\sqrt {n!} } }, \quad n\in\mathbb N.
$$
Does this sequence converge?

Clearly, $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonically increasing.

Therefore, there are two possibilities:

Either the sequence goes to infinity or it is bounded and therefore, converges to a finite limit.

Which of the two holds?

Comment: Interesting Problem!

Comment: Does Stirling's Aprroximation work here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\log a_n&=\log \sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}=\frac{1}{2}\log 1!
+\frac{1}{4}\log 2!+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\log n! \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log (k!)}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=1}^k\log j=
\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \Big(\sum_{j=k}^n \frac{1}{2^j}\Big).
\end{align}
Therefore, the sequence $\log a_n$, which is increasing, converges to
$$
\log a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \Big(\sum_{j=k}^n \frac{1}{2^j}\Big)\longrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}=b<\infty.
$$
Convergence can be established using for example the ratio test.

Thus
$$
a_n\to \mathrm{e}^b=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty k^{2^{-k+1}}.
$$

Note. I am wondering whether $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log k}{2^{k-1}}$ can be expressed in terms of some known constants.